# App Engine upload issues.

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

I'm no longer able to upload code to my app engine app.  The following are the symptoms that I'm experiencing:

- Code compiles and files are uploaded.   Update fails during "Verifying availability"  Here's the specific stuff from the console:

  ```
  Deploying new version.
  ```

  Verifying availability:
      Will check again in 1 seconds.
      Will check again in 2 seconds.
      Will check again in 4 seconds.
      Will check again in 8 seconds.
      Will check again in 16 seconds.
      Will check again in 32 seconds.
      Will check again in 60 seconds.
                       .
                       .
                       .
      Will check again in 60 seconds.
      Will check again in 60 seconds.
      Will check again in 60 seconds.
       on backend null.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Version not ready.

When I look in the Admin Console it indicates that the new version uploaded, however, the old code is still running.  I tried using a different machine to upload a Hello World example to isolate my main development machine and project.  I get the same result with the other machine/app.  I also tried to upload the app from the command line but got the same result.  I ran ***appcfg.sh rollback*** (I'm on a Mac) and it completes without error but still the problem persists.

I don't recall a specific change to my app engine configuration immediately before the problem began, but I had changed the version to 0.1 within a couple of hours of my problems starting.  The app engine rejected the version number due to the period in the version number.  It took a long time to figure this out because the feedback was cryptic.  I mention this because a) the feedback was cryptic and b) the error specifically mentions "Version not ready".

Can anyone help me figure out what I did and how to undo it?  If it helps, my app ID is milkmooseexperimental

Thank you.

Comment: I was having this issue all day yesterday, but it appears fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Server Side issue. I'm experiencing the same problem as well, and have been unable to deploy for the last 12 hours. I'm not sure whether this has anything to do with the scheduled outage window.

Comment: I've created a new appspot app and continued working.  The old one is still broken but the new one works.

Comment: Incidentally, whatever problem that Google were having, they've now apparently resolved it, and uploads should be working again.